# How do you divide a string of random letters into pairs of substrings and replace with new characters continuously in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, replace, split

So I'm working on this project that involves translating a string of text such as "als;kdfja;lsjkdf" into regular charaters like "the big dog" by parsing for certain pairs of letters that translate. (i.e: "fj" = "D")

The catch is I cant simply use the `.replace()` function in javascript, because there are many occurences where it's given the text "fjkl", and needs to find "jk" and *logically* interprets the collision of "fj" and "kl" to say that it's found it. This wont work for me, because for me, it didnt find it, as i am only trying to look at found pairs within 2 characters at a time. (i.e: "fjkl" could only yeild "fj" and "kl".)

(In the end I intend to utilize just the 8 characters "*asdfjkl;*" and set pairs of characters to actual letters. (in this subsitution method, fyi, "fj" OR "jf" would actually be "_"(space). )

in trying to figure out this task in javascript, (I dont know if another language might handle it more efficiently,) I tried utilizing the "split" function in the following way. (Disclaimer, I'm not sure if this is formatted 100% perfectly)

```
<textarea id="textbox"></textarea> 

<script>
var text = document.getElementById("textbox").value; //getting string from the textarea
var pairs = text.split(/(..)/).filter(String); //spliting string into pairs
if(pairs == "fj"){replace(pairs, " ")} //some sort of subsitution
</script>
```

Additionally, if possible, i would like the replaced characters to be fed directly into the textarea continuosly as the user types, so the translation happens almost simutaneously. (I'm assuming this will use some sort of `setInterval()` function?)

If any tips can be given on the **correct formatting** of **which tools** i should use in javascript, that would be very outstanding; Thanks in advance.

if your interested, here is full list of subsitutions im making in the end of this project:

syntax:(X OR Y == result)

AJ JA = F
AK KA = V
AL LA = B
A; ;A = Y

SJ JS = N
SK KS = M
SL LS = S
S; ;S = P

DJ JD = A
DK DK = U
DL LD = D
D; ;D = G

FJ JF = _
FK KF = I
FL LF = T
F; ;F = K

AS SA = C
SD DS = L
DF FD = E

JK KJ = O
KL LK = R
L; ;L = Z

AD DA = -
SF FS = ,
AF FA = .

JL LJ = !
K; ;K = :
J; ;J = ?

-Daniel Rehman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have prepared a code for your requirement. You can bind a function on keydown to allow continuous changes as you type in the textarea.

I am using replacePair method to replace a pair of character by its equivalent uppercase representation. You can inject your own custom logic here.

```
var tb = document.getElementById('tb');
var processedLength = 0;
var pairEntered=false;
tb.onkeydown = function (e) {
    pairEntered=!pairEntered;
    if (pairEntered) {
        var nextTwoChars = this.value.substr(this.value.length - 2, 2);
        var prevPart=this.value.substr(0,this.value.length-2);
        var finalText=prevPart+ replacePair(nextTwoChars);
        this.value=finalText;
        processedLength+=2;
    }
}
function replacePair(str){
return str.toUpperCase();
}
```

jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/218fq7t2/

updated fiddle as per your replacement logic: http://jsfiddle.net/218fq7t2/3/

Comment: Well, i have put sucsessfully wedged these operations into my code, and this method indeed seems to work! :) however, just a slight problem, for some reason i am having a hard time injecting my own subsitutions in replace of the `toUpperCase` logic you provided; is it possible you could give  an example of how a logic like "sl" or "ls" = "s" would fit in this method?

Comment: oh! it seems that the following setup i tried in the bottom part of your code somewhat works. when i try to put a simple `replace()` function in as follows, `function replacePair(str){return str.replace("fj", " ");}` it seems to work... but only every other time. it bewilderingly doesnt translate every other character pair, any ideas why?

Comment: additionally, i cant add any other subsitution logic after i specify the first replacement... so theres that. :/

Comment: Could you please post your replacement logic, I will change my code accordingly.

Comment: would this be it? `function replacePair(str){
return str.replace("fj", "  ");
}`....or are you more looking for the actual subsitutions im making in the end...?

Comment: ^(if your looking for that, i just edited the post showing each subsitution.)

Comment: Thanks, meawhile I am working on the logic, could you please add one test case as well (input string and expected output string)

Answer (score 0):

If you can be assured that certain pairs always translate to the same character, then perhaps a dictionary object can help.

```
var dict = { as:"A", kl:"B", al:"C", fj:"D" ... };
```

And, if your 'decryption' algorithm is 'lazy' (evaluates the first pair it encounters), then you can just travel through the input string.

```
var outputString = "", c, cl;
for (c = 1, cl = inputString.length; c < cl; c += 2) {
   outputString += dict[inputString[c-1] + inputString[c]] || "";
}
```

If your replacement algorithm is not any more complicated than simply looking up which letter the pair represents, then this should do alright for you.  No real logic necessary.

Comment: well, assuming i didnt leave out any important syntax... i dont think that method was sucsessful in my code yet... but i very well may be dropping an important part of that "dictionary" you proposed; did you mean to put quotes around the first part of the object-variable, (so intended to be = { "fj" = "D", ...} ?) or was that not the issue here?

Comment: I didn't fully complete the dictionary, as I do not know which pairs of characters will equate to which full characters.  You would need to write the dictionary object in the syntax I provided with your character-pairs being on the left side of the : and the translated character on the right.  If you wish to put quotes around the character-pairs, that is fine (it won't make any difference to Javascript). And, of course, you must omit the "..." as that will throw a syntax error.

Comment: oh, ok that makes more sense. well then now im very curious to why the code still seems to be unresponsive... have any ideas?

Comment: heres my setup using your code, does anything seem incorrect? `<script>
var dict = {fj:"A", dk:"B"};
inputString = document.getElementById('tb');

var outputString = "", c, cl;
for (c = 1, cl = inputString.length; c < cl; c += 2) {
   outputString += dict[inputString[c-1] + inputString[c]] || "";
}
</script>` (the 'tb' is the id for the textarea by the way.)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do it as follows:

```
var text = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
for (i = 0; i <= text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] == "j") {
         if (text[i+1] == "f") {
             pair = "jf";
             text = text.replace(pair, "_");

    }
}
```

What this would do is it would always, when checking any letter, also check the letter after it during the same step in the procedure. When it finds both letter i and letter i+1 matching up with a pair you are looking for, then the letters will be replaced by a space (or whatever you want), meaning that when the for-loop reaches the next run after a pair was found, the size of the text string will have been reduced by one. Thus, when it increments i, it will automatically skip the letter that made up the second component of the found pair. Thus, "jfkl" will be identified as two different pairs and your algorithm will not be confused.

of course, you would also have to work in the other pairs/codewords into the for loop so that they are all checked in some way

Comment: hmm.. i tried this out in my code, and it appears to be unresponsive to changing the text area, however, regardless, i think this particular method of shuffling one character to the right each replacement wouldnt work 100% of the time, because in some instances, i am (counterintuitively) subsituting the two "random" characters for another two characters that represent a single sound in english. (i am basing the entire alphabet off of phonetics rather than the latin alphbet, [i.e: "th" and "sh" have their own sounds, and therefore are their own letters.)... anywho, thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had hoped my previous answer was enough to get you started.  I was merely providing an algorithm that you could then use to your liking (wrap it in a function and add your own event listeners, etc).

Here is the solution to your problem.  I did not write the entire dictionary.  You will need to complete that.

```js
var dictionary = { "aj":"F", "ja":"F", "ak":"V", "ka":"V", "al":"B", "la":"B", "a;":"Y", ";a":"Y" }

var input, output;

function init() {
  input = document.getElementById("input");
  output = document.getElementById("output");
  
  input.addEventListener("keyup", decrypt, false);
}

function decrypt () {
  if (!input || !output) {
    return;
  }
  
  var i = input.value, o = "", c, cl;
  
  for (c = 1, cl = i.length; c < cl; c += 2) {
    o += dictionary[ i[c-1] + i[c] ] || "";
  }
  
  while (output.hasChildNodes()) {
    output.removeChild(output.firstChild);
  }
  output.appendChild(document.createTextNode(o));
}

window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
```

```html
<textarea id="input"></textarea>
<div id="output"></div>
```